# Bash - how to redirect stdout of a certain thread?

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I have a C program, and it creates threads for doing different tasks. Now, I want to redirect the `stdout` of a certain thread in bash scripts?

Here you can assume that I always have a way to get the process id and thread id, I only want to know if it's possible to do this using bash scripts and how?

Note: This is not about *process*, it's *thread*, and I haven't found any questions related to this yet.

Comment: There is only one `stdout` in a process, all the threads share it, which is why you sometimes have to protect it using some sort of mutex.  That applies to the entire file descriptor table, not just `stdout` (fd 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one console, not one per thread. So when 5 threads write in parallel to stdout, all of that goes into a single sink, basically in nondeterministic ways.

So unless each line contains a specific string that identifies the original thread, you can't take that output apart after the fact.

Alternatively, you could have your threads write to different files! When you don't throw random output together, it is much easier to get to the individual sources later on.